# DLL in microprocessors?

Tags: arm, boot, bootloader, firmware

After several months reading and learning from stackoverflow I have decided to post a question I cannot solve.

I would like to add program code (some kind of .dll) to a microprocessor in real time. I mean, lets say I have a set of functions (for instance 5 filters) running in a microprocessor, and I want the user to load another new function (filter) but just downloading that piece of code to the core, instead of downloading again the former 5 plus the new one (bootloading all firmware).

I have not found any info about how to implement this. Any idea out there?

Comment: Which OS are you targetting? DLLs are a Microsoft thing. Other operating system use e.g. shared object files, which is similar concept but a different type of executable format. Are you expecting this library of filters to be used by other applications on the target device, or just by your application?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to reserve some memory space for your filters. I assume you won't play with the memory mapping, so, let say you choose to keep 4kB at 0x00100000 (it's an example, maybe this address isn't even available on your system). Then you can write your filters, and use a linker script that put your code between 0x00100000 and 0x00100FFF.

Now, you need to find your filters in the code you'll load at 0x00100000. To do so, one solution is to put your functions in specific sections of your program, but this require to have an ELF (or any other linkable format) loader in your firmware. An easier solution is to force at the beginning of your code an array with the addresses of your functions. Then, you load the code at 0x00100000 and just do

```
int (*foo0)(int) = *((int*)0x00100000);
int (*foo1)(int) = *((int*)0x00100004);
int (*foo2)(int) = *((int*)0x00100008);
int (*foo3)(int) = *((int*)0x0010000c);
int (*foo4)(int) = *((int*)0x00100010);
```

And the you have a pointer on each of your functions.

This approach is quiet limited. You must reserve some memory for your filter code, your filter code must fit in it, and your filter code must be standalone: it can't reference any variable or function in your main firmware. On the other hand, it's quiet simple to implement, and should fit the needs of most bootloaders.